# Find an unicode character in a txt - android

Tags: android, unicode

I am reading a txt file containing unicode characters. I need to find whether a specific unicode character exist in this file. The code so far is as follows,

```
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("DistinctWords.txt"), "UTF-8"));

         int i = 0;
        String mLine = reader.readLine();
        while ((mLine != null)) {
           //process line
//unicode value taken from http://codepoints.net/U+0D85
            if (mLine.contains("\u0D85")){
                i++;
            }
           mLine = reader.readLine(); 

        }

        reader.close();
        Log.i("tula", "Ayanna - " + String.valueOf(i));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //log the exception
    }
```

Problem: Value of "i" is always "0". When I open the same text file from notepad I can see the letter but my code fails to find it.

Comment: The value of "i" is always "0". When I open the text file from notepad I can see the unicode character I'm after. But my code fails to find it.

Comment: @TronicZomB Sorry about that. I updated the question.

Comment: Do you have "\u0D85' in the text file or the actual character? It might be possible that `.contains()` is searching the literal "\u0D85"...?

Comment: @TronicZomB I have the actual character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like TronicZomB says, I think you need to be looking for the actual character, like:

```
while ((mLine != null)) {
   //process line
    if (mLine.contains("අ")){
        i++;
    }
   mLine = reader.readLine(); 
}
```

You will want to use an editor that can handle the proper encoding:

- Notepad on Windows will allow you to specify UTF-8 encoding on your file, but you have to set the encoding on the file to UTF-8 from ANSI.
- On mac OS-x you can use TextEdit.  In the preferences, with the open & save tab, you can set the document encoding.
- On Linux StarOffice supposedly works, but I haven't used it.

Comment: I think the issue is with my text file as I typed in a sample text and searched for it using both its unicode and the actual character, both worked fine. Any idea what has gone wrong with the file? If it is the encoding is there a way to change it to a format which I can use? How can know the encoding of the text file btw?

Comment: I put some suggestions on the encoding above.

Comment: your suggestions helped and now it is working. This is what I did, From original .txt file: Ctrl+A => File => New => Ctrl+V => File => Save As => File Name => Change 'Encoding' to UTF-8 => Save